# Norm of Classical (Poissonian) Hamiltonian Operator

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, lie-algebra, poisson-brackets

In the Poissonian formulation of classical mechanics, one finds that the time evolution of the phase space vector $\eta = (q_1,q_2\cdots q_n ; p_1, p_2\cdots p_n)^T$ can be put in terms of the exponential of the Hamiltonian operator.

$$\eta (\Delta t) = e^{\Delta t\hat{H}}\eta_0 \tag{1}$$
where $$\hat{H}(f)=\{f,H\} \tag{2}$$

and $H$ is the standard Hamiltonian of the particular dynamical system. When simply describing a particle in an external potential, the Hamiltonian takes the form

$$H=T+V=\frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}+V(\mathbf{q}) \tag{3}$$

In this case, one can use eqn. (2) and carry out the Poisson brackets to find that

$$\hat{H}=\hat{T}+\hat{V}=\frac{\mathbf p}{m}\cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{q}}-\frac{1}{m}\left(\nabla V(\mathbf{q})\right)\cdot\nabla_{\mathbf{p}} \tag{4}$$

This might look complicated, but if consider a system with only 1 degree of freedom and set $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{p}/m$, and $a(\mathbf{q})=-\nabla V(\mathbf{q})$, then the Hamiltonian operator becomes

$$\hat{H}=v\frac{\partial}{\partial q}+a(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \tag{5}$$

**Question:** How would one go about calculating the norm of the Hamiltonian operator (4)? I would like to know this because my calculations tell me that the stability of numerical algorithms for approximating the solution (1) depends on the norm of the operator \hat{H} multiplied by the respective time step I take, $\Delta t$.

Comment: What do you mean by "norm"? The norm of an operator is only defined if there's a norm on the space it acts on, so what is your norm on the space of classical observables?

Comment: @ACuriousMind (1) I was thinking the standard definition: the smallest number $C$ such that $||\hat{H}\eta ||\leq C||\eta || $ for all phase-space "vectors"$\eta$. That's the only pertinent definition I can see for a numerical algorithm. (2) I was open to any clarification on how the norm would/could/should be defined.

Comment: Then you just shift the question to what the heck $\lvert\lvert \eta\rvert\rvert$ is supposed to be. The phase space, in general, is not even a vector space, let alone a normed space.